# I want to use a job array with Slurm to ask Prokka to process my GCA fasta files to generate output files

Tags: arrays, file, slurm, fasta

There appears to be an issue - although prokka creates a log for each fasta file being processed, it seems to stop half-way through, and ends up only generating all necessary output files for one fasta file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks 1
#SBATCH --time 60:0
#SBATCH --qos castles
#SBATCH --array=1-9
#SBATCH --output=Array_test.%A_%a.out
#SBATCH --error=Array_test.%A_%a.error
#SBATCH --account moradigd-microbial-genomics


module purge; module load bluebear
module load prokka/1.14.5-gompi-2019b


file=$(ls *.fasta | sed -n ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p)
myscript -in $file

prokka --force --species "Campylobacter Jejuni" --outdir prokka-output $file
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I am told there is a pipeline needed for this kind of problem.

Comment: Prokka is designed to run on a single `.fasta` input. Either combine the sequences into one fasta file or run prokka individually.

Comment: On Slurm you can use lots of .fasta files at the same time.

Comment: You are not understanding. prokka runs on one fasta file at a time. So submit multiple slurm jobs for multiple fasta files

Comment: There is a way to run multiple jobs on slurm using Prokka for .fasta files, according to academics from a leading university. Submitting one job at a time on Slurm is pointless if you have 1000 .fasta files to process.

Comment: Slurm job submission can be automated. again this is a slurm question not a prokka one.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how `prokka` works, the following is only speculation, but is looks like having all jobs writing in the same `prokka-output` directory runs into issues where only the last job writing its output can do so successfully.

You could try creating one directory per job in the array

```
prokka --force --species "Campylobacter Jejuni" --outdir prokka-output-$file $file
```

or

```
prokka --force --species "Campylobacter Jejuni" --outdir prokka-output-$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID $file
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I am told there is a pipeline needed for this kind of problem.